# web listbox problems when viewed on an ipad

Tags: ipad, listbox

Ipad converts listboxes to dropdowns.  The problem is that when the list pops up, items longer than about 25 characters are truncated at 25.  Is there anyway to force the popup to display the complete text?

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way for me.

How about some workarounds?

1. Change the select element into a radio element group, for the cost of some space on the webpage?
2. Make two selects out of one e.g. change <.option>Master of Science - Biologie<./option> into a second select box?
3. On selecting an element add a explanatory text next to the select?